# How to keep DataTable persistent?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, ado.net, datatable

I have a `Gridview` filled  by a `dataTable`, filled by a `DataAdapter`. That's how grid is initially loaded in `Page_Load`. 
To add a search funcionality, I make the same  but passing `TextBox.Text` as parameter to the `SELECT... LIKE ...` statement.
To add an edit funcionality(a button in every row) I need the previous data in the `dataTable`, and if I performed a search before editing I need only the result of the search in my  `dataTable`. 
The problem is, I don't know how to keep its value alive (persistent), and `dataTable` has 0 columns when I press teh edit button, so it doesn't display anything to edit.
I guess it happens because I'm using `Using`, and `dataTable` is probably getting cleaned after `End Using`.

In that case, whta can I do to fix it? I thought removing `miconn.Close()` but it doesn't solve anything, in fact, I don't know if connection is still open after `End Using`.

Code:

```
Dim con As New Connection
Dim table As New DataTable()

Private Sub fill_grid()

    Using miconn As New SqlConnection(con.GetConnectionString())
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT area,lider_usuario FROM AREA"
        Using command As New SqlCommand(sql, miconn)
            Using ad As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                ad.Fill(table)
                GridView1.DataSource = table
                GridView1.DataBind()
                'miconn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Not IsPostBack Then
        fill_grid()
        End If

End Sub

Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

        Dim miCon As New Connection
        Using miconn As New SqlConnection(miCon.GetConnectionString())
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT area,lider_usuario FROM AREA WHERE area LIKE @area"
            Using command As New SqlCommand(sql, miconn)
                command.Parameters.Clear()
                command.Parameters.Add("@area", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" + TextBox1.Text + "%"
                Using ad As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                    ad.Fill(table)
                    GridView1.DataSource = table
                    GridView1.DataBind()
                    'miconn.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
End Sub

  Protected Sub EditRow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
        GridView1.DataSource = table
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub

   Protected Sub CancelEditRow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCancelEditEventArgs)
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1
        GridView1.DataSource = table
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why dont you use Caching, Server or Client Side? that is viewstates , sessions , cache

Comment: While searching at google, I tell you I don't know what that is. Can you give an example?

Comment: See my answer below, use of viewstate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BindGrid()
{
   var dt = YourMethodReturningDatatable();
   ViewState["Table"] = dt;
   grid.DataSource = ViewState["Table"];
   grid.Databind();
}

page_load
{
   if(not ispostback) // not because my 1 key stopped working.
   {
     BindGrid();
   }
}
```

Comment: Great, worked! Just a question, after updating(UpdateRow event of the Update button) How can I refresh ViewState?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make two different functions for filling the data table and binding it. Call the filling function before the !IsPostBack condition and do the binding inside the condition. Here is the sample code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim table as new DataTable
        table = GetData() 'The function that would return a data table
        If Not IsPostBack Then
           GridView1.DataSource = table
           GridView1.DataBind()
        End If

End Sub

Private Function GetData() As DataTable
Using miconn As New SqlConnection(con.GetConnectionString())
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT area,lider_usuario FROM AREA"
    Using command As New SqlCommand(sql, miconn)
        Using ad As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
            ad.Fill(table)
            GetData = table
            miconn.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
End function
```

Hope it helps.